# New Year to Buddhists on 1st January?

Tags: ethics, belief

Buddhists have a new year ,But it is not January 1st.What is the reason they celebrate the new year of January 1st.It is based on a religious basis or something else...

Comment: You've mentioned that "Buddhists have a new year ,But it is not January 1st." If it is so, may I know when it is?

Comment: @Damith [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=buddhist+new+year) says it varies, i.e. in some countries it's the first full moon of April, and in others it's the first full moon of January.

Comment: In sri lanka, April consider as New Year Month.  But now it is changing to January

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to celebrate new year any day you like but you have to find many people to agree with you. Otherwise, you have to have an one person party.

Answer (score 0):

...it is based on on something else...called Wisdom.

> **The Heart Sutra**
>
> O Sariputra,
>
> Form does not differ from Emptiness And Emptiness does
> not differ from Form.
>
> Form is Emptiness and
> Emptiness is Form

And

> The **Kalama Sutta** sometimes also called the **common sense sutta**.
>
> Kalamas, when you yourselves know: 'These things are
> good; these things are not blamable; these things are praised by the
> wise; undertaken and observed, these things lead to benefit and
> happiness,' enter on and abide in them.

And

> *Dukkha*

There is suffering in life and it is unsatisfactory. In there if you find little reason to celebrate then celebrate without breaking the eight fold path. Afterall the Buddha never said 'dont look at the fireworks and feel happy'

> *Annicca*

Its all impermenant anyways. New year- No new year - Christian- Buddhist its all going to change. So dont take stuff too seriously. Live mindfully in the present moment. If the present moment brings you a celebration of new year then go for it.

> If you meet a Buddha on the way kill the Buddha

Live like a lotus in mud. Dont get too much attached to ideas. Dont indulge into clinging, even for the Buddha. You have to let-go of everything. Even of Buddhism. Nirvana is in state of letting-go.

> *Mudita*

Buddha taught us to have sympathetic joy that is to rejoice in happiness of others. So if a Christian next door is gonna be happy for his New Year, Buddha told to go and enjoy his cake.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to have a day that reminds one that another year has gone, has been wasted. That date differs also in traditional countries but in most of them people rush to celebrate it around the 13-16 April this days.

In nearly all regions it's related to a certain circle of decay in natures run around, seldom really "religious".

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Sri Lanka and also a Buddhist. In Sri Lanka people consider Start of a new year to be 13 or 14 of April. But its not a Buddhist thing, Hindus in Sri Lanka also celebrate this on April. I think most Asian countries do this on April.